# How to exit a Do While Loop when ColumnDifferences method no longer finds a difference?

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop, difference

I created a macro that searches for any numbered value change in column K using ColumnDifferences, and then inserts a formatted row as a divider between those values. There are no blanks cells between any of the numberd values. Everything works as desired with the exception of the Run-time error '1004' "No cells were found" once the ColumnDifferences method runs out of values to compare. I'm new to VBA, and programing in general. I'm sure there is some simple line of code that I'm missing to exit this loop once ColumnDifferences runs its course. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Divider_On_Column_Difference()
'
Range("K1").Select

Do

Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
ActiveCell.Select

    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10), ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 4
    
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = 1
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = 1
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = 1
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = 1
    End With
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "PATTERNS(1,0,5,TRUE,2,4,0,0)"
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 10).Select
    
Loop While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

End Sub
```

Comment: As an answer to "how to exit a loop"..... `Exit Do` for a Do Loop, and `Exit For` to exit a For Next loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has been revised and simplified.

While it's worth noting that using `Select` is generally not recommended, but it is necessary before applying `PATTERNS`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Divider_On_Column_Difference()
    Dim curCell As Range, endCell As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set curCell = Range("K1")
    Set endCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)
    Do
        If curCell = endCell Then Exit Do
        Set c = Range(curCell, endCell).ColumnDifferences(curCell)
        Set curCell = c.Cells(1)
        curCell.EntireRow.Insert
        With Cells(curCell.Row - 1, 1).Resize(1, 10)
            .RowHeight = 4
            With .Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlMedium
                .ColorIndex = 1
            End With
            .Select
            ExecuteExcel4Macro "PATTERNS(1,0,5,TRUE,2,4,0,0)"
        End With
    Loop While True
End Sub
```

---

Examine the values in column K in reverse order without utilizing ColumnDifferences.

```
Sub Divider_On_Column_Difference2()
    Dim endCell As Range
    Dim c As Range, i As Long
    Set endCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)
    For i = endCell.Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "K") <> Cells(i - 1, "K") Then
            Rows(i).Insert
            With Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 10)
                .RowHeight = 4
                With .Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                    .ColorIndex = 1
                End With
                .Select
                ExecuteExcel4Macro "PATTERNS(1,0,5,TRUE,2,4,0,0)"
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```